# Converting MySql DateTime type into something more friendly

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, pojo

I have a Java web app that reads a MySql db and returns DateTime fields.  What is the best way to convert the DateTime fields returned in the resultset into something more readable?

Currently the DateTime fields print as:

2008-12-14 16:30:00

but I would like something more user friendly like:

14 Dec 2008 at 16:30

I am populating an ArrayList with these dateTimes from a pojo.  I would like to format them before adding to the arrayList, so then I can just print the contents of the arrayList in the JSP.

Answer (score 5):

Another option is to use the JSTL. The formatting library makes it easy to display a date in any format and it is i18n aware. The advantage is that you can leave the date as a Date object and manipulate it as such but only convert it when you need to display. The format tag will look like this:

```
<fmt:formatDate value="${myDate}" dateStyle="MEDIUM"/>
```

Like I said above, one big advantage is that it is i18n aware so you can display the date in a localized format.

The full syntax is:

```
 <fmt:formatDate value="expression" 
     timeZone="expression"
     type="field" dateStyle="style" 
     timeStyle="style"
     pattern="expression"
     var="name" scope="scope"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

Mysql [date_format()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

```
mysql> select date_format(now(),'%d %b %Y at %H:%i') as formated_date;
+----------------------+
| formated_date        |
+----------------------+
| 20 Dec 2008 at 10:56 | 
+----------------------+
```

Comment: Doh! I think this perfectly answers I question I just posted. Should have read this first. Didn't realise I coudl get mysql to format the dates for me. Thanks.

Comment: This is not the right way. You should use JSTL `fmt:formatDate` for this. This way you can just keep a worthfully `Date` object in Java code all the time.

Comment: You are formatting at persistence level, not a good practice. Try sending the datetime itself to the UI and format there!

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer to use a `simpleDateFormat` in the Java code so my code is not *bound* to any database function (weak reason, I know).

```
    Date date = ...
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy 'at' HH:mm");  // Locale?
    String text = df.format(date);
```

Be warned that `SimpleDateFormat` is not thread safe. From the documentation:

> Date formats are not synchronized. It is recommended to create separate format instances for each thread. If multiple threads access a format concurrently, it must be synchronized externally.

Comment: He's using JSP's. The `fmt:formatDate` as mentioned by Vincent Ramdhanie is the **only right way**. It's by the way already backed by `SimpleDateFormat` and automagically already takes locale into account. Reread his answer for the sake that.

Comment: @BalusC as I understood the OP, he would like to format before adding to the list. --ups-- and just now I've seen that the question is quite old...

Answer (score 0):

What kind of abstraction layer do you have over the database? It looks like a simple case of subclassing whatever you're using as the field class, and adding a method for your format.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend the tag formatting option, because you have the real data (dates/times) and you format at page level where format is relevant (and you know.. by example, locale to apply).

If you anyway want to format it and put the strings into a List use `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` as Carlos Heuberger says.