# Java Dateformat Error

Tags: java, date, datechooser

I am using JDatechooser netbeans swing plugin for my desktop app development. By default its dateformat is mm/dd/yy but its not the format which the db required. I need to convert it to the yyyy-mm-dd format. I tried with SimpleDateformat class and it gives me the following error: `com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Incorrect date value: '8/29/11' for column 'registered_date' at row 1`

can anyone give me a good solution to do this properly

Thanks

Comment: The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html). Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67752047/10819573) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67505173/10819573) to learn how to use `java.time` API with JDBC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Date date = ...
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String date_for_mysql = df.format(date);
```

See related SO answers here:

[How to parse a date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999172/how-to-parse-date-in-java)
[Java date formatting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/412435/java-date-formatting)
[Converting MySql DateTime type into something more friendly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383600/converting-mysql-datetime-type-into-something-more-friendly)
[how to store java date type to mysql date type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942270/how-to-store-java-date-type-to-mysql-date-type)
[Convert Date into MYSQL Date Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800593/convert-date-into-mysql-date-format)
[How to convert Date in String to Sql date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6305809/how-to-convert-date-in-string-to-sql-date)
[How to set Current date to MySQL date column from Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395576/how-to-set-current-date-to-mysql-date-column-from-java)

Comment: Thanks a lot, the following link you gave me helped me a lot: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/999172/how-to-parse-date-in-java

Answer (score 6):

Your database doesn't require a particular date format at all - you shouldn't be inserting the data as a *string* in the first place. You should use a prepared statement and use [`setDate`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setDate%28int,%20java.sql.Date%29). Ideally you should perform as few string conversions as possible - you don't need one when getting the value out of the `JDateChooser`, and you don't need one when inserting into the database:

```
// Unfortunately you need to convert from java.util.Date to java.sql.Date
statement.setDate(1, new java.sql.Date(chooser.getDate().getTime()));
```

(Note that you *do* potentially need to bear time zones in mind, but that's a different matter... you can call a `setDate` overload which takes a calendar too.)

If you've been inserting (or querying) data by constructing a full SQL statement including the values, you should stop doing that *right away*. Not only do you have this sort of conversion issue, but you also open yourself up to SQL injection attacks. Always use a prepared statement and specify any parameter *as parameters* rather than including them in the SQL.